# "Сейчас они словят меня!" — можно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, глаголы

Правильно ли говорить "*сейчас они **словят** меня!*"?

Или лучше заменить на "поймают"?

Comment: _Юлия Ермакова: можно ли употребить слово “словят”? Или лучше заменить на "поймают"?_  === И _словят_ можно, и _поймают можно_ и... Выбор слова зависит от контекста.

Comment: @slava1947. А в данном конкретном предложении?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Словить" (кратковременно) можно кайф, оплеуху и т.п.; в других значениях это слово почти перестало употребляться, хотя и фиксируется словарями как разговорный вариант слова "поймать". Лучше сохранилось слово "изловить", которое тоже более характерно для старой речевой практики и сейчас употребляется для разнообразия. Но по отношению к себе не стоит его употреблять (это чаще о звере или о злоумышленнике, о длительных усилиях в поимке). Нейтральное выражение - да, "поймают", "догонят" и пр.

Answer (score 4):

Так выражаться, конечно, нельзя: *словят* в современном русском языке — грубая ошибка.
В рассматриваемом предложении возможно нейтральное слово ***поймают*** или "окрашенные" слова: ***схватят, сцапают, заарканят*** и др.  Но только не "словят"!

Comment: "Словить" – разговорное к "поймать", а вовсе не "грубая ошибка"

Comment: @Niemand Грубая - не грубая -  не нам судить. Это **очевидная** ошибка, если не брать за образец разговор наркоманов или бабок на лавочке.

Comment: ...А также Кузнецова и Ефремову если за оборзец не брать. Да и не только их.  *behemothus*, вас в детстве не учили: если вам что-то *кажется*, то это совершенно не обязательно так и есть. Учитывая ваше языковое чутье, тут скорее будет наоборот.

Comment: Грубая ошибка это "споймать", а словить это просторечное разговорное выражение.

Answer (score 1):

"Словить" - слово разговорно-просторечного и жаргонного ряда. Причем даже к разговорным его относят далеко не все авторы. Так что я бы поостерегся рекомендовать его для широкого использования.

Answer (score 0):

Да, вполне можно.

СЛОВИТЬ, словлю, словишь; словленный; -лен, -а, -о; св. кого-что. Разг. Поймать. Словил старик рыбку. Кот словил мышку.

Comment: Опять Кузнецова цитируете? ))) А он  среди орфоэпистов не слишком авторитетная фигура.  Хотя и не только среди них...

Comment: И не только, и не только... А еще среди кого? Вот вам Ефремова:

слови́ть
сов. перех. разг.
1) Схватить что-л. на лету.
2) Поймать кого-л., что-л. движущееся, удаляющееся.
3) Захватить кого-л. в качестве добычи.
Задержать кого-л. проходящего мимо, удержать уходящего.

Comment: А вот дискутировать с Вами я больше не намерен. Тем более - в таком тоне.

Comment: Эх,  behemothus... Ну, кто ж виноват, что вы все время садитесь в лужу... Это от излишнего стремления посадить в лужу меня, и чем это я вам так досадил, даже и не помню. Прям жалко вас... А с другой стороны - сами же виноваты, вот и мучайтесь. Если ваши минусы хоть немного облегчают ваши мучения - ставьте и дальше, не стесняйтесь.

Answer (score 0):

"В игре её конный не словит" (Некрасов).  Если уж слово употребил классик, да ещё в произведении, входящем в школьную программу, то оно по крайней мере не является ошибкой.  Другое дело, что в 21 веке это слово малоупотребительное, и в 19 веке оно было, наверное, разговорным.

Answer (score 0):

Касательно классика — им господин Некрасов явно не при жизни стал. И уж тем более не в момент написания вышеупомянутых строк они попали в школьную программу)))) Хотя ДА, многие филологи и, в частности, литреды склонны к такому, надо заметить, сомнительному способу решения языковых споров — раз уж классик написал... (Вроде как тот классик живым человеком никогда и не был, а сразу канонизировался.))) По поводу "спіймав-зловив" — на Украине более бытуют формы "упіймав" или "схопив", поэтому прямого влияния не прослеживается.
И уж если ориентироваться на словари, то разговорная форма зафиксирована, а значит, вполне имеет право на существование.

Comment: @Артём Луговой, здравствуйте. Почему Вы убрали запятые до и после "в частности"? Посмотрел еще раз Розенталя (§ 25, п. 9, 9) и ответы здесь https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432791/Обособление-в-частности

Comment: Пример из Розенталя, мне кажется, полностью соответствует предложению в ответе: "Вопросы эти рассматривались в ряде монографий и, в частности, в специальных статьях".

Comment: Или обособить целиком: "в частности литреды",  и убрать союз "и".

Comment: Странно... А я руководствовался ответом 223421 [отсюда](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8(,)).

Comment: Да, я это тоже читал. Там "в частности" обособляется вместе с присоединением, уточнением. То есть можно выделить с двух сторон запятыми "в частности литредами", но без союза "и".

Comment: Я уже спрашивал, как делать гиперссылку в ответах, но в комментариях у меня нет такой функции. Может, это связано с устройством (я с планшета)?

Comment: В ответе 223421 используется оборот "в целом и... в частности" ("...вообще и... в частности"). В этом случае запятые не нужны.

Comment: А-а, действительно! Я же [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/458638/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5/458639#comment472008_458639) писал.

Comment: Артём, спасибо, разобрался. (Просто выделения не видны, когда набираешь комментарий, а только после его отправки.)

Answer (score -4):

Я думаю, что  слово  “ словить " -  это гибрид украинского слова - спiймати  и русского - ловить ...
вот и получился суржик в виде  слова  “словить “…
 я считаю, что истинный русский язык,  как и любой  другой язык,  не должен иметь слов суржика! 
не надо загрязнять языки  ‘недословами’ , которые режут слух ,чтобы сохранить чистоту и красоту языков для последующих поколений  и чтобы 
плебейский диалект  не стал нормой.

Comment: Цитированные фразы не режут слух?  На ответы и комментарии обратили внимание?

Comment: Тогда уже речь скорее должна идти об украинском слове **"зловити"** (https://translate.yandex.ru/?utm_source=wizard&lang=uk-ru&text=%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8). Это слово произносится ***"зловыты"*** и переводится именно как **"поймать"**. На суржике часто его произносят в промежуточных вариантах, например ***"словыты"***. В прошедшем времени - ***"зловыв"/"словыв"***, т.е. почти как **"словил"**.

Comment: @елена, вам уже наговорили слов и наставили минусов, однако в чем-то вы правы. Влияние украинского тут возможно. Вот только злосчастный суржик не стоило вспоминатью Лингвисты не считают такие языковые субстраты источником заимствований. Если влияние, то не суржика, а исходного украинского. Ну и, конечно, поменьше эмоций. Не надо устраивать тут борьбу под лозунгами чистоты русского языка. Не поймут.