# Обособление "в частности"

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение:
Когда его скорбь по античной эпохе и, *в частности*, по греческой утихнет, тогда он будет способен ответить на ваши вопросы.

Правильно ли здесь обособление?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда его скорбь по античной эпохе и, **в частности,** по греческой утихнет, тогда он будет способен ответить на ваши вопросы.

В частности ― обособленное **вводное слово**.

Сравнить: Когда его скорбь по античной эпохе **в общем и в частности** по греческой утихнет, тогда он будет способен ответить на ваши вопросы.

В конструкции  "вообще и ... в частности" запятые на ставятся, это наречия в роли обстоятельства.

Проверено по учебнику "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации".

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**А. Вводное слово**

1) В большинстве случаев наречное выражение "в частности" является вводным словом и обособляется, например: Объектами имущественного страхования могут быть, **в частности,** имущественные интересы.

2) Как и другие вводные слова,  " частности" может использоваться как союз в начале обособленных оборотов (не отделяется от оборота запятой): В этом фильме особенно проявился ее талант,  **в частности комедийный.** Кадры фильма сопровождались инструментальной музыкой, созданной с использованием электронных и струнных инструментов, **в частности скрипки**.

**Б. Наречное выражение в функции обстоятельства**(не обособляется)

1) Обычно это конструкции вида "в общем/целом - в частности), например: Думал о вас, о привлекательности **вообще** и вашей **в частности**.

Но вот пример, где "в частности" является вводным словом **в роли союза**: У детей появляются замкнутость, что негативно сказывается на их **общем** психическом развитии, **в частности на развитии высших психических функций.**

2) В других случаях "в частности" в роли необособленного обстоятельства **практически не встречается.** Вот, пожалуй, редкий пример, где автор не обособил обстоятельство: У меня в районе создание сайтов и **портал в частности** считают моим личным делом. Другой возможный вариант (значение уточнения): У меня в районе создание сайтов,  и портал в частности,  считают моим личным делом.

Comment: То есть таким образом (заменой "в частности" на "в общем и в частности") можно проверять, когда в частности является вводным словом, а когда нет?

Comment: Я не всегда доверяю методу проверки, лучше использовать грамматический анализ. В дополнении к ответу я привожу пример такого анализа.

Answer (score 2):

У вас неправильная пунктуация. Надо вот так расставить знаки препинания:  Когда его скорбь по античной эпохе, в частности по греческой, утихнет, тогда он будет способен ответить на ваши вопросы. Союз И сознательно убрала, так как он здесь лишний.

Comment: Нужно было подчеркнуть в предложении, что хотя греческая эпоха является частью античной, рассматривается она отдельно и поэтому союз и тут нужен был.