# Необходимо ли здесь тире?

Tags: пунктуация

"Две розы", "Ягоды шиповника" и "Маки" — это все названия известных картин.

Comment: Да, необходимо)

Comment: «Все названия»? Необходима замена Е на Ё.

Answer (score 3):

Тире в этом предложении обязательно.

Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба главных члена предложения выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа.

Тире ставится перед словами ***это, это есть, значит, это значит, вот***, присоединяющими сказуемое к подлежащему.

См. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92).

Comment: @Артём Луговой  Не могли бы Вы подсказать, как менять ссылку на одно слово или предложение на русском.

Comment: На панели сверху значки B and I (курсив и жирный), потом после небольшого отступа как раз значок гиперссылки. Выделяете слово или слова, на которые хотите сделать гиперссылку, нажимаете на тот значок и вставляете в нужное поле саму ссылку.

Comment: И [вот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/50049/%d0%93%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%9f%d0%9e%d0%94%d0%a1%d0%9a%d0%90%d0%97%d0%90%d0%a2%d0%ac) ещё.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Артём!

Comment: Не за что) По ссылке почитали? Последняя делается так: [текст](ссылка с https).

Comment: Да, о "подсказать" читал раньше; хорошо, что напомнили.

Answer (score 1):

Да. Тире ставится перед словами *это*, *это есть*, *значит*, *это значит*, *вот*, присоединяющими сказуемое к подлежащему.